# Why it's never enter the button click and make the FillRectangle?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private class MyRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
  protected override void OnRenderButtonBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e)
  {
    var btn = e.Item as ToolStripButton;
    if (btn != null && btn.CheckOnClick && btn.Checked)
    {
      Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, e.Item.Size);
      e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Transparent, bounds);
    }
    base.OnRenderButtonBackground(e);
  }
}
```

I want that when i move the mouse over the button or click on it then make the fillrectangle.
But it's never pass the line:

```
if (btn != null && btn.CheckOnClick && btn.Checked)
```

I used a breakpoint when i move the mouse cursor over the button it stop on:

```
if (btn != null && btn.CheckOnClick && btn.Checked)
```

And continue never enter. Something wrong with the IF line.

EDIT:

This is what i see when i move the mouse over the button:

[image: Mouse cursor over button]

And i want that when i move the mouse cursor over the button or/and click on it , it will keep to be transparent like it's in original state. This is the original state when im running my program and mouse cursor is not over the button:

[image: Original]

This is the code im using now:

```
private class MyRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
        {
            protected override void OnRenderButtonBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e)
            {
                var btn = e.Item as ToolStripButton;
                if (btn != null || btn.CheckOnClick || btn.Checked)
                {
                    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, e.Item.Size);
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Transparent, bounds);
                }
                 base.OnRenderButtonBackground(e);
            }
        }
```

It's getting to the lines:

```
Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, e.Item.Size);
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Transparent, bounds);
```

But still the color around the button is this light blue like in the first screenshot i uploaded.
Any way to change it ?

What i want to do is like in internet explorer 11 when you move the mouse over the icons/images in the top right corner the icons/images change the color but there is no rectangle around it:

This is a screenshot from internet explorer regular state:

[image: Internet explorer mouse cursor not over]

And this is internet explorer when the mouse cursor is over one of the icons/images:

[image: Internet explorer mouse cursor is over icon/image]

Comment: I guess you need to review your rules on this if, what you want to check? What is your need?

Comment: You can select and hover over the 3 conditions to check which is unexpectedly false..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think painting with transparent is going to have any visual effect. That would be like painting with water.

If you don't want something painted, you would override the painting method, and then NOT call the `base` method and do nothing else. Eg:

```
protected override void OnRenderButtonBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e) {
}
```

However, this doesn't always work. It will depend on whether that is actually where the painting you want to prevent is.

Comment: Sahuagin i tried your solution in fact i used my own MyRenderer class code i just didn't use the base line. And in all cases i checked so far it's working. I didn't understand when it shouldn't work ? In what situation/s it won't work ?

Comment: @user3788761 if it works, it works. I don't know how you're using this class so I can't test it. By "it doesn't always work" I mean that it all depends if this is the right method to override. Also I've seen some controls where you might expect to be able to stop some drawing by doing this, but the drawing doesn't go away. But if you try it and it works, then it's working.

Comment: Sahuagin last question sorry. I added a mouse enter event of the toolstrip button and inside i tried to color the forecolor in red but it dosent do anything. private void toolStripButton1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toolStripButton1.ForeColor = Color.Red; 
        }  Why it's not coloring it in red ?

Comment: @user3788761 you should probably open a new question to ask that. as far as I know `ForeColor` refers to the text color. It will change the color of the letters. use `BackColor` to change the background color of a toolstripbutton.